# React: Communicating state between two sibling components

Tags: reactjs, blueprintjs

I am using a third-party react library ([blueprintjs](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/tabs.tab)) with a `Tab` component that's used like this:

```html
<Tab
    id="notifications"
    title={<span>"Notifications"</span>}
    panel={<div>The content of the page</div>}
/>
```

Instead of being rendered directly, it's parent component `Tabs` renders all children components that are of type `Tab`.

I would like to link the `title` and `panel` props together, so that I can show a badge in the `title` element, based on the state of the `panel` element:

[image: The title element with a badge based on what the panel shows]

How should I go about this?

My initial ideas:

1. Get the number of unread notifications from the panel element via a ref and pass it to the title element as a prop
2. Move state up one level. This feels awkward -- I want the management for the notifications to stay in the notifications page.
3. Have a `<NotificationTab ... />` element which handles state for the panel + the title together. The problem with this method is that the parent `Tabs` component will not recognize non-`Tab` components.

Note: I am aware that there are several questions about this, but the answer is always "lift the state into the parent component". I really would rather not do that, since the parent component doesn't have anything to do with notifications -- it just switches tabs.

Comment: "...since the parent component doesn't have anything to do with notifications -- it just switches tabs" But what you are asking makes the adding of notification # to each tab's title a concern of *a* parent component. Now whether or not this lifted state lives in your `Tabs` container, a parent's parent or higher, or app state (i.e. redux) is up to you. Lifting state *somewhere* and passing as props is the pattern and answer as you've discovered.

Comment: @DrewReese Fair enough. If you post that as an answer I'd accept it.